# If a finite group has no element of order $2,$ does every element have a unique square root?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite group. Are these two statements about it equivalent?

1. $\forall g \in G \exists ! h \in G$ such that $h^2 = g$
2. There are no elements of order $2$ in $G$

It is quite obvious that the first statement implies the second one:
if $g = e$, then $h = e$ is the only possible $h$.

However, I do not know whether the second statement implies the first one or not.

Comment: It is true for abelian groups, which you can show by proving that the map $h\to h^2$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose $(2)$. By [Cauchy’s theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), the order $n$ of the group is an odd number, $n=2m+1$. Now given $g\in G$, take $h=g^{m+1}$ it satisfies $h^2=g$ and it is unique because if $h^2=h’^2$ then $h^{2(m+1)}=h’^{2(m+1)}$ or $h=h’$ becaue $h^{2m+1}=e=h’^{2m+1}$,
and $(1)$ follows.

Comment: Uniqueness is not clear *at all* here. Working without pen and paper, I cannot see why it follows from there being no element of order $2$.

Comment: Well $G$ is finite, so if the map $g \mapsto g^2$ is surjective then it must be injective.

Comment: @user1729, I edited my answer, I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose there are no elements of order $2$ in $G$, then every element is of odd order.

Suppose $g^{2r-1}=1$ then $(g^r)^2=g$ - so there is at least one element - $g^r$ - whose square is $g$.

Suppose now $h^2=g$ so that $h^{4r-2}=1$ and $(h^{2r-1})^2=1$, then $h^{2r-1}$ is not of order $2$ so $h^{2r-1}=1$ and $g^r=h^{2r}=h$. So the element whose square is $g$ is unique.

Comment: Answer on the nose!